# How to change text datatype to numeric value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, text, casting

I am trying to change the data type in mysql, but keep getting an error message.

My column includes product price and it has price info, but its data type is set as text. So I can't use average or sum function. I've tried to use CAST and Alter table syntax but I just can't change it. Could you please help? Below are an example I used... I put 'double' 'number' 'numeric' etc but MYSQL doesn't recognize any of those.

```
alter table furniture.furniture modify product_price double;
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `but keep getting an error message` That statement should always be followed by the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in order to change the data type of a column to decimal is:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DECIMAL;
```

Take care that your column must not include non numeric characters (except sth like 5.28) because otherwise this will fail.
If you don't want to change the datatype of the column, but only change it within a query, you can create such a select:

```
SELECT CAST(columnname AS DECIMAL) FROM tablename WHERE columnname REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

The where clause makes sure to only select numeric values. You can just remove it if not necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.. I really appreciate it. I tried both syntaxes but they all didn't work. I wonder if I can't change text to numeric at all.

Comment: Please provide more details because otherwise no one can help you ;) What does not work? Which is the complete error message? Could you please provide your DB schema and data and the SQL command you tried here? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0